# Comment traduire « to read about » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comment traduiriez-vous la phrase suivante :

> We read about Austria in the next chapter.

« Nous lisons au sujet de l'Autriche » est particulièrement hideux. Quelles suggestions proposez-vous pour rendre cette expression anglaise en français ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

J'utiliserais “nous parlerons de”.

Selon le contexte, on doit aussi pouvoir utiliser “nous découvrirons”, “nous discuterons de”, “nous aborderons le sujet de”, etc.

On peut aussi utiliser le présent: “nous découvrons”, “nous discutons”, “nous abordons”. Cela dépend du contexte. Si c'est plus loin dans le même ouvrage, l'usage du futur me semble plus naturel en français (mais le présent ne me gêne pas en anglais, va comprendre !).

Comment: J'ai accepté la réponse, cela dit j'ai l'impression que ta suggestion force l'utilisation du futur alors que la phrase d'origine est au présent.

Comment: Que la phrase d'origine soit au présent me paraît justement bizarre. C'est tiré d'un livre?

Answer (score 8):

Ça dépend du contexte, mais effectivement « nous lisons au sujet de l'Autriche » ne passe pas. Le verbe « lire » ne peut pas mettre en relation le texte avec son sujet, il implique vraiment l'action de lire. Dans une critique de livre, j'utiliserais spontanément « le chapitre suivant parle de l'Autriche » (ou éventuellement « traite de l'Autriche », l'utilisation de « parler » pour un texte écrit est très courante mais à éviter dans un registre très soutenu).

Si le contexte force vraiment le point de vue du lecteur, on pourra dire quelque chose comme « dans le chapitre suivant, nous découvrons l'Autriche ».

On peut quelquefois utiliser le nom « lecture » : « le chapitre 3 est une lecture intéressante sur l'Autriche ». Sinon, le verbe peut s'employer dans un contexte tel que « pour la semaine prochaine, lisez le chapitre sur l'Autriche ».

Answer (score 1):

Comme il s'agit du futur, il faudrait dire "Nous lirons sur l'Autriche", ou une autre variante, mais sans oublier d'indiquer qu'il s'agit du futur.

Comment: Où est la marque du futur dans la phrase ?

Comment: J'ai peut-être manqué quelque cours de français, mais j'étais sur que "nous lirons" était la 1ère personne du pluriel du verbe lire au futur. Dans la phrase en exemple, "in the next chapter" implique que c'est dans le futur.

Comment: certes, mais le verbe anglais est au présent (ou au passé d'ailleurs).

Comment: Et pourtant la solution que vous avez accepté emploie un verbe au futur. Mais peu importe, je ne suis pas là pour argumenter.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que cela dépend du verbe :

```
We talk about Austria.
```

se traduit par :

```
Nous parlons de l'Autriche.
```

Je traduirais :

```
We read about Austria.
```

par :

```
Nous lisons sur l'Autriche.
```

Comment: « Nous lisons sur l'Autriche » est mieux, mais ça reste assez désagréable à lire je trouve.

Comment: @Raphink: En effet. On développe souvent en *Nous lisons un livre/chapitre/ouvrage sur l'Autriche*, mais ce n'est plus une traduction littérale.

Comment: Traduction littérale vs style de texte, c'est souvent un dilemne bien compliqué pour les traducteurs...

Answer (score 0):

La langue anglaise est fantastique dans la mesure ou un même  verbe suivi de différentes prépositions exprime une multitude de sens.

Ex: To read about, to read into, to read in, to read against, to read from, etc.

Le français n'a pas cette flexibilité. C'est pourquoi "We read about Austria in the next chapter" se traduirait par "Nous lirons un texte sur l'Autriche dans le chapitre suivant."

Comment: « Fantastique » est peut-être exagéré, sachant qu'il s'agit d'une source de confusion pour les personnes apprenant l'anglais, la compréhension du sens global n'étant pas toujours intuitive même si l'on connait le sens individuel de chacun des éléments (par ex.: take off). Je dirais que les «multi-word verbs » sont une spécificité de l'anglais que l'on ne retrouve pas en français. *To read about* est cependant assez clair, mot à mot « lire à propos ».

Comment: @jlliagre: Ben non, dans ce cas là ça se rapproche de « donner un cours », ça n'a rien a voir avec « lire » lorsque ce n'est pas oral… Cf. les réponses précédentes.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Mon commentaire était à propos du qualificatif « fantastique », sa dernière phrase ne signifiait pas que le mot-à-mot était approprié, seulement qu'il permettait de se faire une idée des intentions de l'auteur, contrairement à *take off*, *check out*, *give up* et autres. *Read about* prépare le lecteur à la lecture du chapitre suivant qui va traiter de l'Autriche. Une nuance est que l'auteur écrit ici comme s'il était en compagnie du lecteur et qu'ils allaient lire ensemble la suite alors qu'en français, on écrirait plutôt, « nous parlerons, nous aborderons, etc. »

Answer (score 0):

Selon le contexte :
- Au chapitre suivant, nous aborderons/étudierons/évoquerons/examinerons le cas de/nous pencherons sur/l'Autriche.